# How to get multiple phone numbers used by user in flutter for Registration?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to get all the list of phone numbers used by user and then show them in a pop up and let the user select one for receiving otp. I have checked multiple packages in pub dev but all of them are showing the current sim number or default sim in the phone. But I want to show the all the numbers of the user that been used previously in the pop up . Example image been attached below .[image]